# Java Improvements and NullPointerException

Tags: java, web-applications, nullpointerexception, platform

This is my first time posting here so sorry if i make any mistakes. :/

Ok, I have worked a BIT with java before never really tried to make a game until now.
I tried to make a simple platformer with Walls but they make it hard for me.
I have a simple code setup now:

People wanted the stacktrace..(Old one i fixed this but i got new error see further)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Start.start(Start.java:27)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

(old) exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at level.getStartDirt(level.java:9)
at Start.start(Start.java:28)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

newest stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Start.paint(Start.java:75)
at Start.update(Start.java:67)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Line 75:

```
level.paint(g);
```

Line 68:

```
paint(doubleG);
```

Start class:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


public class Start extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener{

private Image i;
private Graphics doubleG;
//--Square s1;
Dirt dirt[];
level lvl;

@Override
public void init() {
    this.setSize(800, 600);
    addKeyListener(this);

}

@Override
public void start(){
            level lvl = new level();
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    lvl.getStartDirt();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    //thread information

    while(true){
        //--s1.update(this);
        repaint();      

        try {
            Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void update(Graphics g) {
    if(i == null)
    {
        i = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        doubleG = i.getGraphics();
    }

    doubleG.setColor(getBackground());
    doubleG.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

    doubleG.setColor(getForeground());
    paint(doubleG);

    g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this);

}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    lvl.getPaintDirt(g);
    //--s1.paint(g);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {


}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {


}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


}

}
```

Sqaure class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;


public class Square {

private int x = 500;
private int y = 25;
private int width = 50;
private int height = 50;
private double dx = 0;
private double dy = 0;
private double gravity = 15;
private double energyloss = .65;
private double xFriction = .9;
private double dt = .2;

public Square(int sx, int sy){
    x = sx;
    y = sy;

}

public void update(Start sp){
    if (x < 0){
        x = 0;
        dx = -dx;
    }else if (x > sp.getWidth() - 50){

        x = sp.getWidth() - 50;
        dx = -dx;
    }else{
        x += dx;
    }


    if(y == sp.getHeight() - 50 -1){
        dx *= xFriction;
        if (Math.abs(dx) < .8){
            dx = 0;
        }
    }

    //gravity
    //if(y > sp.getHeight() - 51){
    //  y = sp.getHeight() - 51;
    //  dy *= energyloss;
    //  dy *= -1;
    //}else{
    //  if (Math.abs(dy)< (gravity/dt)/5.25 && y == sp.getHeight() - 51){
    //      dy = 0;
    //      y = sp.getHeight() - 51;
    //  }


        //position  formula
        y += dy*dt + .5*gravity*dt*dt;
        dy += gravity *dt;


}

public Rectangle getBoundries(){
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    return rect;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);

}

}
```

Dirt class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Dirt {

int x,y,width,height;

public Dirt(int sx, int sy){
    x = sx;
    y = sy;
    width = 50;
    height = 50;
}

public void destroy() {

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);

}

public Rectangle getBoundries(){
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    return rect;
}

}
```

level class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class level {
Dirt d[] = new Dirt[9];

public Dirt[] getStartDirt(){

    d[1] = new Dirt(400, 600);
    d[1] = new Dirt(0, 600);
    d[2] = new Dirt(50, 600);
    d[3] = new Dirt(100, 600);
    d[4] = new Dirt(150, 600);
    d[5] = new Dirt(200, 600);
    d[6] = new Dirt(250, 600);
    d[7] = new Dirt(300, 600);
    d[8] = new Dirt(350, 600);


    return d;
}

public void getPaintDirt(Graphics g){

            d[0].paint(g);
    d[1].paint(g);
    d[2].paint(g);
    d[3].paint(g);
    d[1].paint(g);
    d[4].paint(g);
    d[5].paint(g);
    d[6].paint(g);
    d[7].paint(g);
    d[8].paint(g);
}

}
```

Still some questions:
-I get a NullPointerException when running, why/ what does it mean?
-Is there an easier way to make multiple Dirt thingies in the lvl?
-I heard there was a better way of doing the collision (@ dirt.getBoundries w/ intersect)

Thanks!
Greets, Tim.

Comment: Post details about your exception, e.g. a stack trace

Comment: And always include the relevant code, etc., *in the question itself*, not in external sites. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-OsQJk4BxERA/Tpcl4QSmDcI/AAAAAAAAAfU/MtjQjyPQ8bg/s641/Stacktrace+or+GTFO.jpg

Answer (score 2):

The comments to you question make a good point.  Having a quick look it doesn't seem like you create the lvl variable - unless its done via DI?

But the stack trace will usually give you the exact line that is the problem.

Comment: Ok, i added the level but i get a new NullPointerExcption should i make a new post?

Comment: @TimvanOsch I think maybe just put the stack trace here - and we'll have a look, maybe update the original post with the new code?

Comment: Ah - in level (should be Level btw) you have a null Dirt array - need to initialise it, say Dirt[] d = new Dirt[9];

Comment: It would really help if you could get the line numbers into the code you've posted - but given whats in the stack trace, and the code you have here it looks like lvl is null - which would make sense - you've created a shadow variable, not initialised the lvl variable at the class level

Comment: Thanks i just removed all the lvl initializers and added this code to top: Level lvl = new Level(); and i added a Function thats get called to the Level class. But it doesnt do anything.(The function.) But now it works like charm :D Thank you! anyway to put this on solved?

Comment: Seems to be sorted now - so would be good to mark it solved I think